# Drawing vectors I found with block matching algorithm not finding any changes

Tags: c#, vector, signal-processing

I am trying to implement a block matching algorithm on the luminance values of an image.

I have never seen it implemented so had to take liberties with how I do it.

The mean difference function looks like this and I think it works pretty well:

```
/// <summary>
/// intended to loop over the 8x8 chunk and calculate the MAD
/// </summary>
/// <param name="C">Original frame</param>
/// <param name="R">New frame</param>
/// <param name="x">x coord in the new matrix to check</param>
/// <param name="y">y coord in the new to check</param>
/// <param name="oi">old i index in old frame. stays the same</param>
/// <param name="oj">old j index in the old frame</param>
/// <param name="N">block size (8)</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static float MeanDifference(List<List<float>> C, List<List<float>> R, int x, int y, int oi, int oj, int N ) {
    float MAD = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (i + oi < C.Count && j + oj < C[i].Count && i + x < R.Count && j + y < R[i].Count)
                MAD += Math.Abs(C[i + oi][j + oj] - R[i + x][j + y]);
        }
    }
    return MAD /= (N * N);
}
```

I believe the problem is coming from the way I loop but I cannot say for sure.

```
/// <summary>
/// Step function advances the seach algorithm through the indexes.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="i">vertical index by which we search</param>
/// <param name="j">horizontal index by which we search</param>
/// <param name="width">width of search (16)</param>
/// <param name="height">height of search(16)</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool Step(ref int i, ref int j, int width, int height) {
    if (j + 1 + 8 < width) {
        j++;
    }else if (j + 1 + 8 >= width && i + 1 + 8 < height) {
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
/// <summary>
///  Search algorithm
/// </summary>
/// <param name="C"></param>
/// <param name="R"></param>
/// <param name="searchSize"></param>
/// <param name="oi"></param>
/// <param name="oj"></param>
/// <param name="sx"></param>
/// <param name="sy"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Tuple<Point, Point> Search(List<List<float>> C, List<List<float>> R, int searchSize, int oi, int oj, int sx, int sy) {
    int i = sy;
    int j = sx;
    int height = searchSize;
    int width = searchSize;

    float lowest = 1000;
    Point sp = new Point(oi, oj);
    Point ep = new Point();

    bool keepStepping = true;

    while(keepStepping) {
        float mad = ExaustiveSearch.MeanDifference(C, R, i, j, oi, oj, 8);
        if (mad < lowest) {
            lowest = mad;
            ep.X = j;
            ep.Y = i;
        }
        keepStepping = ExaustiveSearch.Step(ref i, ref j, searchSize, searchSize);
    }


    return new Tuple<Point, Point>(sp, ep);
}
```

Function that calls everything:

```
List<Tuple<Point, Point>> vectorData = new List<Tuple<Point, Point>>();
for (int i = 0; i < leftPicture.Height; i+=8) {
    for (int j = 0; j < leftPicture.Width; j+=8) {
        vectorData.Add(ExaustiveSearch.Search(Manager.LumList, Manager2.LumList, 16, i + 8, j + 8, i, j));
    }
}
```

The problem I seem to be having even with simple test cases is that for an image that is identical and has only a portion shifted to the left I end up with vectors that not only don't detect the shift but also just point down.

This is what I see when I draw the vectors out.[image: dog picture with eye shifted left]
(yes I draw the vectors on the original image)

I am hoping that anyone with some knowledge of the block search algorithm would shine some light on what I am doing wrong or show me how someone would actually go about implementing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone ever has this issue again here is some code to work back from.

Test code:

```
DataManager manager = new DataManager();
Image im1 = Image.FromFile("./pic1.jpg");
Image im2 = Image.FromFile("./pic2.jpg");

manager.SetLeftPicture(im1);
manager.SplitBytesIntoColorSpaces();
manager.DrawYcbcrOnRightBitmap(1);
first.Image = manager.LeftImageBitmap;

DataManager manager2 = new DataManager();
manager2.SetLeftPicture(im2);
manager2.SplitBytesIntoColorSpaces();
manager2.DrawYcbcrOnRightBitmap(1);
second.Image = manager2.LeftImageBitmap;

List<Tuple<Point, Point>> mvs = new List<Tuple<Point, Point>>();

for (int oi = 0; oi < manager.LumList.Count; oi += 16) {
    for (int oj = 0; oj < manager.LumList.Count; oj += 16) {
        List<List<float>> C = manager.LumList.GetSquare(oi, oj, 16);
        List<List<float>> R = manager2.LumList.GetSquare(oi, oj, 16);
        List<List<float>> checkBlock = C.GetSquare(4, 4, 8);
        float mad = ExaustiveSearch.MeanDifference(checkBlock, R, 8, 4, 4);
        Point sp = new Point(oi + 4, oj + 4);
        Point ep = new Point(oi + 4, oj + 4);

        for (int i = 0; i < oi + 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < oj + 8; j++) {
                float nmad = ExaustiveSearch.MeanDifference(checkBlock, R, 8, i, j);
                if (nmad < mad) {
                    mad = nmad;
                    ep = new Point(i + oi, j + oj);
                }
            }
        }
        mvs.Add(new Tuple<Point, Point>(sp, ep));
    }
}

Bitmap map1 = new Bitmap(manager.LumList.Count, manager.LumList.Count);
Bitmap map2 = new Bitmap(manager2.LumList.Count, manager2.LumList.Count);

for (int i = 0; i < map1.Height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < map1.Width; j++) {
        map1.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb((int)manager.LumList[i][j], 0,0,0));
        map2.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb((int)manager2.LumList[i][j], 0, 0, 0));
    }
}
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(map1)) {
    Pen p = Pens.AliceBlue;
    foreach (Tuple<Point, Point> mv in mvs) {
        g.DrawLine(p, mv.Item1, mv.Item2);
    }
}

first.Image = map1;
second.Image = map2;
```

Code for GetSquare

```
public static List<List<T>> GetSquare<T>(this List<List<T>> data, int x, int y, int block) {
    List<List<T>> output = new List<List<T>>();
    for (int i = x; i < block + x; i++) {
        List<T> dat = new List<T>();
        for (int j = y; j < block + y; j++) {
            dat.Add(data[i][j]);
        }
        output.Add(dat);
    }
    return output;
}
```

code for mean diff

```
public static float MeanDifference(List<List<float>> C, List<List<float>> R, int N, int x, int y) {
    float MAD = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (j + y >= N || i + x >= N) continue;
            MAD += Math.Abs(C[i][j] - R[i + x][j + y]);
        }
    }
    return MAD /= (N*N);
}
```

Output: [image: Dog!]